# Nuget Error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

### Getting error while running command in VS 2019 Package manager console

### Command Used: nuget install runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.app -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

---

PM> nuget install runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.app -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Feeds used:
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installing package 'runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.app' to 'C:\Users\DF\source\RT\DFG\RET\sample.
CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.app/index.json
WARNING: An invalid cache entry was found for URL 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.app/index.json' and will be replaced.
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.app/index.json
OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.app/index.json 255ms
nuget : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.app' from source 'nuget.org'.
At line:1 char:1

- nuget install runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.app -Source https://a ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (An error occurr...ce 'nuget.org'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  ```